# How to model data in Cassandra for last 100 events for a customer

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql

We have multiple customers with each customer running multiple sensors. Each sensor logs data frequently (event 20s). How do I create a data model in Cassandra to answer this query?

We have thought of the data model like this for other queries:

```
Create Table Data{
  CustomerId,
  SensorId,
  Date,
  DataTime
  SensorData1,
  SensorData2,
  Primary key ((CustomerId, SensorId, Date), DataTime) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To satisfy a query of the last 100 events for a customer, you'll need to make two adjustments to the model above:

1. Adjust your PRIMARY KEY definition to partition only on your `CustomerId` and your date bucket (`Date`).  Then, you'll want to cluster on `DataTime`.  To ensure uniqueness of sensor, you'll probably also want to add `SensorId` on the end.
2. Add a `CLUSTERING ORDER` with a sort direction of `DESC` on `datatime`.  This will cluster your data on-disk by `datatime`, sorted with the most-recent times first.

Basically, I created your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sensordata2 (
    customerid uuid,
    datebucket text,
    datatime timeuuid,
    sensorid text,
    sensordata1 text,
    sensordata2 text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((customerid, datebucket), datatime, sensorid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (datatime DESC, sensorid ASC);
```

After inserting some test rows, I can now query the last 10 sensor readings `WHERE customerid 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f` like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT customerid, datebucket, sensorid, dateof(datatime), datatime, sensordata1, sensordata2
FROM sensordata2 WHERE customerid=3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f 
AND datebucket='20150515' LIMIT 10;

 customerid                           | datebucket | sensorid | dateof(datatime)         | datatime                             | sensordata1 | sensordata2
--------------------------------------+------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------
 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f |   20150515 |       A1 | 2015-05-15 10:34:34-0500 | e3a15c20-fb17-11e4-93da-21b264d4c94d |          47 |          24
 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f |   20150515 |       A1 | 2015-05-15 10:34:34-0500 | e39ffc90-fb17-11e4-93da-21b264d4c94d |          46 |          23
 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f |   20150515 |       A1 | 2015-05-15 10:34:34-0500 | e39e4ee0-fb17-11e4-93da-21b264d4c94d |          45 |          22
 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f |   20150515 |       B1 | 2015-05-15 10:34:22-0500 | dc64a340-fb17-11e4-93da-21b264d4c94d |          47 |          24
 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f |   20150515 |       B1 | 2015-05-15 10:34:22-0500 | dc60aba0-fb17-11e4-93da-21b264d4c94d |          46 |          23
 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f |   20150515 |       B1 | 2015-05-15 10:34:22-0500 | dc5d0220-fb17-11e4-93da-21b264d4c94d |          45 |          22
 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f |   20150515 |       A1 | 2015-05-15 10:32:16-0500 | 90e27fa0-fb17-11e4-93da-21b264d4c94d |          47 |          24
 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f |   20150515 |       A1 | 2015-05-15 10:32:16-0500 | 90e0aae0-fb17-11e4-93da-21b264d4c94d |          46 |          23
 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f |   20150515 |       A1 | 2015-05-15 10:32:16-0500 | 90de8800-fb17-11e4-93da-21b264d4c94d |          45 |          22
 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f |   20150515 |       A1 | 2015-05-15 10:25:24-0500 | 9b5d1ae0-fb16-11e4-93da-21b264d4c94d |          47 |          24

(10 rows)
```

Comment: Your example is very useful. Thanks. One question, how will this model be affected for a customer with 1000+ sensors and if a customer requests data frequency of 5 seconds?  I could split the date bucket to hours, but was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: Even at a data frequency of once per second, you'll still be under the limit of 2 billion columns per partition (3 cols per CQL row x 86400 seconds per day x 1000 sensors = 259,200,000 cols).  But yes, the way to get more granular in your partition storage is to split the date bucket further down.